# Installing Rubinius 2.0.0-rc1 on CentOS 6.3 - it complains no libyaml found though i installed it

Tags: ruby, centos, rubinius

Please do not advise `RVM` related solutions, I do not use it. I'm installing Rubinius from source. I've previously installed `libyaml` in `/usr/local`. Any of the following attempts detailed below fail with no shared object libyaml-0.so.2 found:

```
./configure --with-lib-dir /usr/local/lib

# same for

./configure --with-lib-dir /usr/local/lib --with-include-dir /usr/local/include
```

There is no need to point the `lib` dir to `lib64` because `locate libyaml` shows `libyaml` is installed in `/usr/local/lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `/usr/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should work for you:

before configure do like this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```